# EGL shared context and multiple codec input surfaces: camera preview rotated and scaled

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I'm using the [GL part of LibStreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/tree/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/gl) and I modified parts of it to be able to attach multiple codec input surfaces. I basicly just modified the addMediaCodecInputSurface, removeMediaCodecInputSurface and run functions of the SurfaceView class.

```
public SurfaceManager addMediaCodecSurface(Surface surface, FrameReadyI frameReadyCallback) {
    SurfaceManager mSurfaceManager = new SurfaceManager(surface, mViewSurfaceManager);
    mCodecSurfaceManager.add(mSurfaceManager);
    frameReadyCallbackList.add(frameReadyCallback);
    return mSurfaceManager;
}


@Override
public void run() {

    mViewSurfaceManager = new SurfaceManager(getHolder().getSurface());
    mViewSurfaceManager.makeCurrent();
    mTextureManager.createTexture().setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

    mLock.release();

    try {
      while (mRunning) {
        synchronized (mSyncObject) {
          mSyncObject.wait(20);
          if (mFrameAvailable) {
            mFrameAvailable = false;

            mViewSurfaceManager.makeCurrent();
            mTextureManager.updateFrame();
            mTextureManager.drawFrame();
            mViewSurfaceManager.swapBuffer();

              if (mCodecSurfaceManager.size() > 0) {
                for (int idx = 0; idx < mCodecSurfaceManager.size(); idx++) {
                  try {
                    mCodecSurfaceManager.get(idx).makeCurrent();
                    mTextureManager.drawFrame();
                    mCodecSurfaceManager.get(idx).setPresentationTime(ts);
                    mCodecSurfaceManager.get(idx).swapBuffer();
                    /* the next time I call  ViewSurfaceManager.makeCurrent(); the preview image will be garbled */
                    this.frameReadyCallbackList.get(idx).OnFrameReady(ts);
                  } catch (Exception ignore) {  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
    } finally {
      mViewSurfaceManager.release();
      mTextureManager.release();
    }
```

}

This code is working perfectly on most devices. 
[image: preview how it looks on most devices]

On the Galaxy S6 however, the camera preview is getting rotated and scaled down as soon as one of the codec input surfaces is made current. I attached an image to clarify what happens. 
[image: preview after media codec input surface has been made current]

As long as I don't draw onto that surfaces, the preview is working perfectly. 
I had a look at the GL traces and noticed, that the glUniformMatrix4fv matrix gets modified after I draw onto the input surfaces, but I don't know what to do with that information.

## Update 1:

I traced this down a little further. When I start the camera preview I create a context (context 0) in which the camera preview is drawn onto my preview surface. When I then add the codec input surfaces, a new context is created for each of these. Now here comes the problem: I add, lets say, 2 codec input surfaces (contexts 2 and 3). In the GL trace I can clearly identify these and have a look at their transformation matrices for each call of drawFrame(). But an additional context (context 1 in galaxy_s6.gltrace) is created which seems to also draw onto the preview surface, and the method trace shows that the calls are different from all other contexts. All other contexts call the same methods in the same order, just not this one. To see if this only happens with the Galaxy S6 I also made a trace on a Nexus 9. It turns out that on both devices a third context is created, but the camera preview is working perfectly on the Nexus 9 (actually on all other devices I tested yet). I added the traces just in case somebody wants to have a look at them.

[Galaxy S6 GL trace](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vua5xlcip7saq6x/galaxy_s6.gltrace?dl=0)

[Nexus 9 GL trace](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4zqbsl1t8i3a17/nexus_9.gltrace?dl=0)

## Update 2:

I found out that context 1 is actually the context that draws all the UI elements of the app. Nevertheless, I struggle to find out what causes the rotated and scaled down camera preview. I should maybe point out that the recorded video is neither rotated nor scaled, its just the preview that is messed up.

Comment: @fadden have you got any clue as to where I should look for an error?